# Android: String of date to Date format

Tags: java, android, date

I have a string : "2012-08-10" which represents : "yyyy-MM-dd"

I have tried to convert it to a date format using the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
 Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(eventDates.get(i));
```

However the log gives the following types of dates:

```
Fri Aug 10 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2012
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `eventDates`? A string array?

Comment: PLEASE Post the code you are using for logging the date.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct, your log uses its own representation of date, if you want the same format then you need to use

```
dateFormat.format(dateInstance);
```